# How change x labels data in ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

How to change the x data/label units? typing "exam 1", "exam 2", "exam 3",... instead of 1, 2, 3, ...

```
notas = {{6.3, 5.2, 4.70, 8.70, 3.05}, {8.95, 6.25, 7.20, 8.20, 
   8.5}, {4.95, 2.15, 2.80, 3.70, 2.4}, {5.7, 4.6, 4.80, 3.85, 
   3.25}, {0.65, 0.3, 0.05, 0.10, 0.1}, {4.1, 1.7, 0.30, 0.10, 
   0.1}, {2.05, 1.05, 1.55, 0.20, 1.75}, {5.5, 6.6, 5.25, 8.10, 
   8.6}, {6.2, 7.5, 9.45, 6.30, 8.4}, {3.95, 4.35, 7.85, 5.90, 1.25}}

a = ListLinePlot[notas, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1.6], LabelStyle -> {20, Bold} , 
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
  GridLines -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}]
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `Ticks`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Tells me that "A tick position should be a number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly specify each tick marks with specific labels by adding the following option in the plot command:

```
Ticks -> {
  {{1, "Exam 1"}, {2, "Exam 2"}, {3, "Exam 3"}, {4, "Exam 4"}, {5, "Exam 5"}},
  Automatic}
```

Note that the `Automatic` is there to manage the ticks on the $y$ axis.

Also note that the first tick is disappearing due to the positioning of the $y$ axis, which takes priority over it. This can potentially be avoided by switching to `FrameTicks -> (*same*), Frame-> True`.