# How to type the First s-label in ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

How to put the first x tick (in red) in x axis?, 
[image]

```
notas = {{6.3, 5.2, 4.70, 8.70, 3.05}, {8.95, 6.25, 7.20, 8.20, 
   8.5}, {4.95, 2.15, 2.80, 3.70, 2.4}, {5.7, 4.6, 4.80, 3.85, 
   3.25}, {0.65, 0.3, 0.05, 0.10, 0.1}, {4.1, 1.7, 0.30, 0.10, 
   0.1}, {2.05, 1.05, 1.55, 0.20, 1.75}, {5.5, 6.6, 5.25, 8.10, 
   8.6}, {6.2, 7.5, 9.45, 6.30, 8.4}, {3.95, 4.35, 7.85, 5.90, 1.25}}

a = ListLinePlot[notas, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1.6], LabelStyle -> {20, Bold} , 
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
  GridLines -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}]
```

Comment: Using one of the `Ticks` settings from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165613/how-change-x-labels-data-in-listlineplot), set the first tick to something like `{1,Style["Exam 1",Red]}`.

Comment: @eyorble for the Style yes, but I thinkk taht the first data is not showed starting at (1,0).

Comment: Please see my most recent edit on the answer to the other question, I address the first tick not appearing there already.

Comment: @eyorble Yes, Thank you. You solved my question with the explanation at   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165613/how-change-x-labels-data-in-listlineplot

Answer (score 2):

Custom ticks defined, and `DataRange` and `PlotRangePadding` used.

```
notas = {
   {6.3, 5.2, 4.70, 8.70, 3.05}, {8.95, 6.25, 7.20, 8.20, 8.5},
   {4.95, 2.15, 2.80, 3.70, 2.4}, {5.7, 4.6, 4.80, 3.85, 3.25},
   {0.65, 0.3, 0.05, 0.10, 0.1}, {4.1, 1.7, 0.30, 0.10, 0.1},
   {2.05, 1.05, 1.55, 0.20, 1.75}, {5.5, 6.6, 5.25, 8.10, 8.6},
   {6.2, 7.5, 9.45, 6.30, 8.4}, {3.95, 4.35, 7.85, 5.90, 1.25}};

xlabels = Transpose[{Table[i, {i, 0, 6.8, 0.2}],
     Flatten@Table[{i, "", "", "", ""}, {i, 0, 6}]}] /.
   {1., 1} -> {1, Style["Exam 01", Red, 16]};

ylabels = Rest@Transpose[{Table[i, {i, 0, 11.5, 0.5}],
     Flatten@Table[{i, "", "", ""}, {i, 0, 10, 2}]}];

a = ListLinePlot[notas, ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1.6], LabelStyle -> {20, Bold},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, GridLines -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}},
  DataRange -> {1, 5}, PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  Ticks -> {xlabels, ylabels}]
```

[image]