# How to avoid this kind of error saving graphs?

Tags: plotting, graphics, save

I can´t save graphs 1 month ago. (I must capture graphs for use it)

How to avoid this kind of error when you are saving the graph?
[image]

Trying to save this graph: 
[How change x labels data in ListLinePlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165613/how-change-x-labels-data-in-listlineplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, It seems a bug .... a long time ago! :-) like Star Wars!

commented at [Failure to export graphics by right-click when Notebook magnification is changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16539/failure-to-export-graphics-by-right-click-when-notebook-magnification-is-changed)

The solution is fit the Window Zoom to 100%
[image]